# Should I Learn C# or C++?

Tags: c#, java, c++

When I first became interested in programming, I took a class that introduced me briefly to C++ for a semester (this class mostly focused on topics like "what is a variable", so I know very little about what C++ is capable of). Up next was a year of AP Computer Science, where I learned Java. Don't get me wrong, I love Java, but I feel like I have become so dependent on it. I am pretty good at programming in Java, and I like the extensive packages like Swing and io that give a great degree of power to even a new learner.

I have exhausted my school's (extremely) limited supply of Computer Science classes and am looking at Internet tutorials or books to learn on my own. However, I don't want to start learning a language only to realize that it isn't "right" for me.

I guess what I am looking for is a widely used, well-known, powerful language that will not only be good for controlling a computer but also for opening doors later in my life.

I am specifically looking at C# or C++, although I don't know why. If you think some other language would be better, please suggest it and why. Hopefully this is enough information for someone to answer. If not, please ask me to clarify because I really would like a specific good answer.

Comment: This question is a better fit for programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @FishBasketGordo Programmers moderator here. Questions like this aren't a good fit there. In fact, generic "what language should I learn" questions are off-topic entirely.

Comment: `Should I learn C# or C++?`, Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no *right* answer to this question.  It depends on what you want to do.  I suggest doing some research as to each language and decide from there.  If you have more specific things that you would like to achieve, then maybe we can help point you in the right direction.

Good luck.

Comment: I looked around a little bit, but most sites I've seen are really biased one way or the other. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should go for c# or Java.  Both these languages are good enough to cater to any kind of computation needs, whether its web, mobile, embedded or just a standalone app.